# How to create a Custom Keyboard Shortcut for Rename [x] items… in macOS Finder?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

The problem in using the standard procedure (via System Preferences… > Keyboard) is that it needs the *exact* command name…

Many thanks in advance for any answer.

--
kenNash

Comment: I'm disappointed that this is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any wildcard which could be used there, probably there is none.
But there is a silly workaround:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Also, this can be easily done in the **Automator**.
Create new Automator document like this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder"
        tell menu 1 of menu bar item 3 of menu bar 1
            click (menu item 1 where name starts with "Rename")
        end tell
    end tell
    return input
end run
```

It has to be saved to the `~/Library/Services/` directory.
Then set your keyboard shortcut for  service:
[image]

You will also need to give accessibility permissions to finder:

[image]

Comment: Then try creating automator service for it.

Comment: Geez! macOS is worse than I tought